# Delete first 15 lines from multiple CSV files in one folder using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a Powershell script that neatly deletes the first 15 lines from single CSV file.

```
$import = get-content c:\temp\test.csv
$import | Select-Object -Skip 15 | Set-Content c:\temp\test2.csv
```

I would like to loop this through multiple CSV files in a single folder. Can't quite figure out how to do this.

Comment: I don't have to tools to test with but from memory this should work: `Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\text.csv | Select-Object -Skip 15 | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\test2.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: use `Get-ChildItem` to grab a list of files, then iterate thru that list by piping to `ForEach-Object`, put your code in the 'F-O` loop. that seems like it would cover your task. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a **single-pipeline solution** that processes the files as *text* files and **skips the first 15 *data* rows**, i.e., preserves the header row (the first line in a CSV file, which contains the column names), and **saves the result for each `*.csv` file to a corresponding `*2.csv` file**:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Filter *.csv | ForEach-Object {
  Get-Content $_.FullName | 
    Where-Object { $_.ReadCount -eq 1 -or $_.ReadCount -ge 17 } |  
      Set-Content ($_.FullName -replace '\.csv$', '2$&')
}
```

<sup>Note: To **unconditionally remove the first 15 *lines***, replace the `Where-Object` command with:

`Select-Object -Skip 15`</sup>

Note the use of the `.ReadCount` property, which contains the input line number. `Get-Content` adds this property to each line that it reads from the input file.

**Processing the CSV files as a *text* files** (with `Get-Content` / `Set-Content` rather than with `Import-Csv` / `Export-Csv`) allows for **faster processing** (and preserves the presence / absence of double-quotes arounnd the values), but there's a **caveat re assuming that *text lines* are the same as *CSV rows***:  while a CSV *row* is *typically* the same as a text-file *line*, that isn't *necessarily* true: CSV column values, if `"..."`-enclosed, may *span multiple lines*.

Also note that in Windows PowerShell `Set-Content` will create "ANSI"-encoded output files by default, *irrespective of the input encoding*; in PowerShell *Core*, you'll end up with BOM-less UTF-8-encoded files. **Use `-Encoding` to control the output encoding.**

Answer (score 0):

Optional `-NumberOfLines` parameter, defaults to `15`.

Optional `-Verbose` parameter will output files modified.

```
function Remove-CSVLines {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$FolderPath,

        [int]$NumberOfLines = 15
    )
    process{
        $fileList = (Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Filter '*.csv')

        foreach ($file in $fileList){
            $csvObject = Import-Csv -Path $file.PSPath
            $csvObject | Select-Object -Property * -Skip $NumberOfLines | Export-CSV -Path $file.PSPath -Force -NoTypeInformation
            Write-Verbose -Message "Removed $NumberOfLines lines from $file"
        }
    }
}

Remove-CSVLines -FolderPath .\myfolder
```

Comment: You've packaged the functionality nicely, but at the end of the day I think the packaging is somewhat of a distraction from the essence of the solution. As it turns out (and it's not obvious from the question), the OP truly wanted to remove the first 15 _lines_ from the files, which apparently contain non-CSV data. Your solution works for proper CSV files whose first 15 _data rows_ should be removed, but note that the round-tripping via `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` is both expensive and may change the quoting and encoding characteristics of the file (`-Encoding` is your friend re the latter).

Comment: Note that `Select-Object -Property *` needlessly creates _copies_ of the input objects; in this case, and for the purpose of (re)-exporting to CSV, this is merely an inefficiency, but note that with non-custom objects as input, information may be lost. In short: use `Select-Object -Property * -Skip $NumberOfLines` to skip `$NumberOfLines` objects and pass the remaining objects through _as-is_.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Would you mind expanding on how using Select-Object could cause loss of non-custom objects? Always looking to improve my knowledge.

Comment: Using `Select-Object -Property ...` creates "property-bag" objects of type `[pscustomobject]` that (b) are (obviously) of a different type than the input objects, (b) have _static copies_ of the input objects'  properties, and (c) are missing any non-property members present on the input objects, notably methods.